# Access Denied error while trying to open notepad on Remote machine using WMIC

Tags: cmd, wmic

I am trying to open notepad on remote machine using WMIC command

```
C:\Users\raj.kamal>WMIC /node:192.168.0.104  process call create 'cmd.exe /c notepad.exe'
ERROR:
Description = Access is denied.
```

I am already logged on to remote machine but I don't why this error is coming.

When I try to pass username and password using WMIC Command, it throws "Invalid Global switch" error.

```
WMIC /username:Raj /Password:"Dummy D" /node:192.168.0.104 process call create 'cmd.exe /c notepad.exe'
```

Can anyone suggest how to handle this error?

Comment: Will `WMIC /username:Raj /node:192.168.0.104 ...` run with typing right password when asked?

Answer (score 0):

I think insteas of `/username` should be `/user`. Then use:

If password is literally `"Dummy D"` including surrounding double quotes:

```
WMIC /user:Raj /Password:"Dummy D" /node:192.168.0.104 process call ...
```

If password is literally `Dummy D` without surrounding double quotes but with a space:

```
WMIC /user:Raj /Password:Dummy^ D /node:192.168.0.104 process call ...
```

---

To be honest, I don't *know* how to spell a password containing a space character (ASCII `0x20`) as a command line parameter - neither in CLI nor in a batch script.

Although I don't like the word *impossible*, this is the case...

More in excellent [Christopher84's comments on passwords and spaces](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5347347-45e7-4d00-806d-8d836af3ed1d/certutil-p-password-with-space?forum=csharpgeneral). Summarizing: "As a general rule, **do not try to put spaces into passwords**! Same goes for usernames, computernames and other unique, human readable identifiers".

Comment: Thanks! I tried as suggested by you but now it throws error " Access is denied" `C:\Users\raj.kamal>WMIC /user:Raj /Password:"Dummy^ D" /node:192.168.0.104 process call create 'cmd.exe /c notepad.exe'
ERROR:
Description = Access is denied.`

Comment: Do I need to make any change in DCOM Configuration for this? @JosefZ

Comment: Even I tried with the password which doesn't contain any space but it didn't worked. It throws the same error "Access Denied". I am not able to find out the reason behind this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run programs with a GUI on remote machines.

From Help

> The Create WMI class method creates a new process. A fully-qualified path must be specified in cases where the program to be launched is not in the search path of Winmgmt.exe. If the newly created process attempts to interact with objects on the target system without the appropriate access privileges, it is terminated without notification to this method.
>
> For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.